# AWS: eb setenv in boto3 (Python)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto3

I need to set my Elastic Beanstalk environment variables from a Lambda using Python. In short, I would need to do a `eb setenv` ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html)) but from a Python API like [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html).

Does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [update_environment](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#ElasticBeanstalk.Client.update_environment). Then you would specifigy your env variables using `OptionSettings` with namespace [aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalkapplicationenvironment) .

Answer (score 0):

Following Marcin's answer, here is what I did:

```py
client = boto3.client("elasticbeanstalk")

client.update_environment(
    ApplicationName="my-app",
    EnvironmentName="my-env",
    OptionSettings=[
        {
            "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment",
            "OptionName": "my-env-variable",
            "Value": "my-value",
        }
    ]
)
```